# How to sort custom post type by multiple custom fields?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

How to display posts with 'agenda' custom type ordered by custom fields 'agenda_date' and then by 'agenda_time'?

'agenda_date' is date custom fields.
agenda_time is text custom fields

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
$agenda_arg = array('post_type' => 'agenda',
 'cat' => $cat_id,
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'agenda_date',
        'value' => date("Y-m-d"),
        'compare' => '>='
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'agenda_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'agenda_time',
);
```

Comment: Can't you combine agenda_date and agenda_time as agenda_full_date and have both agenda_date and agend_time as one and sort by that? and have the other two for the listning.

Comment: Actually you need to use `meta_query => array( array( ... ) )`...

Answer (score 0):

Some note about your code - no need to comment it with "not working", as it's meant as explanation, not as "solution" to work something out through guessing.

### Saving data

This is the most annoying thing: No one should save date and time in different columns. Just makes no sense. At least PHP date and time handling class is named `DateTime` for a reason.

About `date( 'Y-m-d' )`: You know that this gives you just the current day back?

### Data types

Meta queries allow for `type` arguments and got `DATE` and `DATETIME` available. Then there's no possibility to `date()` on time values. There's `time()` (for the current time) for it.

```
$agenda_arg = array(
    'post_type' => 'agenda',
    'cat' => $cat_id,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'agenda_date',
            'value'   => date( "Y-m-d" ),
            'type'    => 'DATE',
            'compare' => '>='
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'agenda_time',
            'value'   => time(),
            'type'    => 'DATETIME',
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    ),
);
```

As last note: I'd try dropping the `agenda_time` array first just to see if it works.